# Is there a way to tell for what range $\lfloor\frac xy\rfloor = n$?

Tags: number-theory

Given $x$, is there a way to tell for what range of $y$ $$\left\lfloor\frac xy\right\rfloor = n?$$

(Where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have
$$
n\le\frac{x}{y}<n+1.
$$
If $x>0$ then $y$ must be also positive, and you get
$$
\frac{x}{n+1}<y\le\frac{x}{n}.
$$
I leave to you the case $x\le0$.